# KSQLDB, create table from a kafka topic not working?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have created a kafka topic, here's is the schema.

```
# topic_name: test.rf.partner

{
  "connect.name": "test.RF.partner.Value",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "partnerID",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Value",
  "namespace": "test.RF.partner",
  "type": "record"
}
```

I tried to create a table using,

```
CREATE TABLE partner (partnerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR) WITH 
    (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'test.RF.partner',VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

Then when I do this the result I am getting is empty data, the data from topic is not going into the table,

```
SELECT * FROM partner EMIT CHANGES;

ksql> SELECT * FROM partner EMIT CHANGES;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|PARTNERID                                                                                           |NAME                                                                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Update:

```
ksql> PRINT 'rytfit.RF.partner' FROM BEGINNING;

Key format: JSON or HOPPING(KAFKA_STRING) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_STRING) or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: AVRO
rowtime: 2021/09/27 19:07:05.563 Z, key: {"partnerID":100}, value: {"partnerID": 100, "name": "kalai"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/09/27 19:07:05.564 Z, key: {"partnerID":101}, value: {"partnerID": 101, "name": "kal"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/09/27 19:07:05.564 Z, key: {"partnerID":102}, value: {"partnerID": 102, "name": "kalai"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/09/27 19:07:05.564 Z, key: {"partnerID":103}, value: {"partnerID": 103, "name": "Intelles"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/09/27 19:07:05.565 Z, key: {"partnerID":104}, value: {"partnerID": 104, "name": "kala"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/09/27 19:07:05.565 Z, key: {"partnerID":105}, value: {"partnerID": 105, "name": "kala"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/09/27 19:07:05.565 Z, key: {"partnerID":106}, value: {"partnerID": 106, "name": "kala"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/09/27 19:07:05.566 Z, key: {"partnerID":107}, value: {"partnerID": 107, "name": "partner"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/09/27 19:07:05.566 Z, key: {"partnerID":108}, value: {"partnerID": 108, "name": "part"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/09/27 19:07:05.566 Z, key: {"partnerID":109}, value: {"partnerID": 109, "name": "par"}, partition: 0
```

Comment: Did you set the auto offset reset? Is data being written to the topic? Are you able to print the topic with ksql?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I executed this `SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';` command to reset the offset to earliest and then I tried to print the topic in `ksql` and it is printing few things like above. Can you check the edition last section of question. Since its printing the topic, why is the create table command not working here for me.

Comment: Did you initially run the `SET` before the `CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes. It is still not populating into the table. I checked all resources online for all of them its populating. Is it because of how data is in my topic? Please help

Answer (score 0):

It happens the same to me for any existing topic. However, a workaround is to create a stream first and then a materialized view with the aggregator method `LATEST_BY_OFFSET`

```
CREATE TABLE partners AS
SELECT  partnerID,
        LATEST_BY_OFFSET(name) AS name 
  FROM partners_stream
GROUP BY partnerID
EMIT CHANGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this be because the documentation states the following?

> In ksqlDB, a table can be materialized into a view or not. If a table is created directly on top of a Kafka topic, it's not materialized. Non-materialized tables can't be queried, because they would be highly inefficient. On the other hand, if a table is derived from another collection, ksqlDB materializes its results, and you can make queries against it.

I'm wondering about the same question myself btw, I'm new to kafka.

Also found this:

https://books.japila.pl/ksqldb-internals/demo/table-isnt-queryable/#ksqldb-internals

Seems like you can't query non materialized tables.